# How to get a website image url when inputted on textbox/textarea

Tags: php, image

I am trying to get an image from a website when inputted on a `textbox/textarea` but I am having a hard time with it.

Basically, its like `facebook` when you try to share a url. Facebook extracts an image from that **URL** and pastes that somewhere below. I want to do something like that but to no avail.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: I scrapped it away since its not showing me the right solutions. I was trying to implement http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I was hoping there are other solutions for this.

Comment: If you want it to happen as soon as you chose/insert the link, you'd need AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this.May be this is what you need [image extract from url](http://www.99points.info/2010/07/facebook-like-extracting-url-data-with-jquery-ajax-php/)

Answer (score 0):

May be this will helpful to you

```
$contents= file_get_contents('http://mydomain.com/folder/image.jpg');
```

here http://mydomain.com/folder/image.jpg comes from textbox or textarea.

Comment: If this not helpful please let me know.. I will find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you input a URL into an input/textarea, you would have to do a couple of things. file_get_contents of the site, then preg_match_all of the src's of the images. Then you would need the user to allow which image they wanted to select (google+ does a nice job of this). This would best be served up by ajax.